# Send input value to typescript (without button send)

Tags: html, angular

I have a regular input text:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" oninput="sendInput()" />
</form>
```

I want to send what the user typed in the box into the typescript file (without a submit button or something) when the user has finished typing, send the input to the typescript.

I try with [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oninput) but it's not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i8eyct) use ngModel two way binding

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputParam"/>    
<p>{{inputParam}}</p>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtxp1x) or use ViewChild as a way

component.ts

```
inputParam=""
  @ViewChild('input') _input: ElementRef;
  sendInput(){
    this.inputParam= this._input.nativeElement.value;
  }
```

html part

```
<form >
    <input #input type="text" (input)="sendInput()"/>
</form>
{{inputParam}}
```